# Передача формы POST-запросом

Tags: csrf, django

Не могу передать форму post'ом в Django. Что только не пробовал, ничего не помогает.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   .....................
   .....................
   url(r'message/$', feedback, name='feedback'),
)
```

**Форма:**

```
    <h1>Обратная связь</h1>
    <form action="{% url feedback %}" method="post" id="feedback" name="feedback">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" class="important" required placeholder="Пожайлуста представьтесь" name="name">
        <input type="tel" class="important" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
        <input type="email"class="important"  required  name="email" placeholder="Ваш email">
        <textarea name="message">Текст обращения</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" id="send">
    </form>
```

**Представление:**

```
def feedback(request):
    return render_to_response(tpl,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (

    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)
```

**Вот ошибка:**
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: [Все по инструкции?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

Comment: Я раз 10 её перечитывал и делал все как написано

Comment: А зачем и middleware, и декоратор?

Comment: Да потому что ничего не помогает(

Comment: В доках написано `Alternatively, you can use the decorator`, вот и попробуйте убрать.

Comment: С ним или без него, все равно не пашет

Comment: XHR == XmlHttpRequest? Ajax балуетесь? Там в доках про него тоже упоминается.

Comment: Да не я народостях MIDDLEWARE отключил, а так ajax есть но яего отклячил вроде как

Comment: Блин какое то ограничение по комментам. Если не ошибаюсь тег {% csrf_token %} должен создавать hidden поле, но его нету.

Comment: А контекст процессор у вас добавлен? Возможно из-за него и не работает у вас этот тег.
И скажите, какая версия Django у вас? Там были некоторые изменения с CSRF от релиза к релизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном коде все верно. Даже проверил [ompldr.org: jt.tar.bz2](http://ompldr.org/vZG41aw/jt.tar.bz2).
Расшаривайте остальное.

Comment: Угу все исправил, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Версия Django 1.3.1. В контекст добавлял точно не помню что но с ним тоже не работало.